# How to establish ngModel two way data binding for custom inputs e.g. on a radio button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a problem implementing my own radio button element in Angular.

Following code is the the markup I'll want to get working **parent component**:

```
<form>
  <my-radio [(ngModel)]="radioBoundProperty" value="1" name="myCustomRadioButton">Btn 1</my-radio><br>
  <my-radio [(ngModel)]="radioBoundProperty" value="2" name="myCustomRadioButton">Btn 1</my-radio><br>
</form>

<p>
  The value of radioBoundProperty is:
</p>
<pre>{{radioBoundProperty|json}}</pre>
```

So far I've build a custom radio component implementing `ControlValueAccessor`.

Bringing data (e.g. value, label) into `my-radio` component is working but cannot get the selection back into my parent component via ngModel two way data binding.

Even when I change the value of `radioBoundProperty` initially it's value overwrites the `value` attribute of both my-radio's

**Update this stackblitz now is a working example**

[stackblitz](https://angular-custom-radio-element.stackblitz.io) with the now working example [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-radio-element?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emit the value to parent using a `registerOnChange` function.

```
export class RadioModel implements ControlValueAccessor { 
    onChange = (val: string) => { };
    onTouched = () => { };
    onApplied = () => { };

    writeValue(val: string): void {
        // when the ngModel change it comes under writeValue function
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (val: string) => void): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    valueChanged(){
         this.onChange('your value');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the `ControlValueAccessor ` within the my-radio component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-radio-element?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio.component.ts

Comment: Implemented the valueChanged and mapped to <input>s change event and it's wrking once now. but once I've checked the radio then both radios become the current ngModel value (updated the stackblitz)

Comment: @Bernhard Add a ngmodel to radio input https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-radio-element-9mustp?file=src/app/radio.component.ts